# CMake: How to compile each node with a specific flag

Tags: catkin-make, ros-kinetic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this is really a CMake question. Let's say I want to compile the source for node 1, 2 and 3 with -pthread, -O3 and -Os flags respectively. How should I specify this in `CMakeLists.txt` and/or `catkin_make` command?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289983/cmake:-how-to-compile-each-node-with-a-specific-flag/) by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 249 on 2018-04-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you can you the `set_target_properties` command to set many things including compiler flags just for one target.

You would add:

```
set_target_properties(<your_binary> PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "<your custom flags>" )
```

See the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_target_properties.html) for more details.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2